# No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://localhost:51020/university

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

```
import java.sql.*;
public class a2 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try{
      Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/univ_db", "postgre", "astronaut.pd");
      PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("select id from student");
      ResultSet Rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
      while(Rs.next()){
        System.out.println(Rs.getInt(5));
      }
    }catch(Exception ex){
      System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }}}
```

I am trying to connect my server with my databse, and I do not know what i did wrong on this. I tried to search it online but I did not find any solution.

Error:

> No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/univ_db

Comment: What does this have to do with SQL Server? This appears to be related to Java and PostgreSQL (and nothing to do with SQL as a language, or the RDBMS SQL Server). I've updated the tags for what this appears to actually be related to.

Comment: Also, that comment should be in your question, not as a comment. I've edited it in for you, but please do make use of the edit feature. Thanks.

Comment: As I don't see an error in the URL itself, this means that likely you do not have the PostgreSQL JDBC driver on the class path when running your application.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this error you need to get driver class reference `using Class.forName()` before getting connection using `DriverManager.getConnection()`

Example:

```
Class.forName(“org.postgresql.Driver”);
```

Important: *Remember to import postgree driver to your java project.*

Comment: This is unnecessary in a simple Java application since 2006 with Java 6 (assuming a JDBC 4 or higher compliant driver) as the driver is loaded automatically. More likely the OP doesn't have the driver on the class path.